# PowerShellで、半角スペースのあるディレクトリ(以下)を削除したい

Tags: windows, powershell

**削除したいディレクトリ名**

> [日本] 東京 大阪

**削除したいディレクトリパス**
以下のディレクトリを再帰的に削除したい

```
L:\1\地図\[日本] 東京 大阪\
```

---

**試したこと1**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-Location -Path L:\1\地図

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Item -Path [日本] 東京 大阪
Remove-Item : 引数 '東京' を受け入れる位置指定パラメーターが見つかりません。
```

ダブルクォーテーション付与。何も削除されませんでした

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Item -Path "[日本] 東京 大阪"
```

シングルクォーテーション付与。何も削除されませんでした

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Item -Path '[日本] 東京 大阪'
```

---

**試したこと2**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-Location -Path "L:\1\地図[日本] 東京 大阪"
Set-Location : パス 'L:\1\地図\[日本] 東京 大阪' が存在しないため検出できません。
```

Comment: `[ ]` が使われているのが話をややこしくしていそうです。試したこと2 は単純にパスを間違えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[角括弧]`は正規表現で使用されるメタ文字なので、`-Path`または省略時のパスとして使用すると通常の文字列として解釈されません。
そのため、角括弧を通常の文字列として扱いたい場合は`-Path`の代わりに[`-LiteralPath`](https://nasunoblog.blogspot.com/2016/07/powershell-bracket-literalpath.html)を使います。
またはバッククォートを使うことで、エスケープすることができます。

下記のいずれかの記述で削除できるはずですのでお試しください。

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "[日本] 東京 大阪" 
Remove-Item -Path '`[日本`] 東京 大阪'
Remove-Item -Path "``[日本``] 東京 大阪"
```

Comment: 手元の環境では削除できるのですが…。2番目と3番目の結果は`地図`と`[日本] 東京 大阪`の間にバックスラッシュがありませんが、パスとエラー文字列にお間違えありませんでしょうか？(パスが間違っている場合、1番上の結果はコメント通りの挙動となります)

Comment: パスを間違えていました(この件については別途質問します)。現状「アクセスが拒否されました」と表示されてしまいディレクトリを削除することができません。管理者としてPowerShell実行しているのですが、takeownか何かを実行する必要がありますか？

Comment: おそらく所有者の変更か管理者ユーザによるアクセス権の見直しが必要な状況だと思われます。ほかに考えられる原因はLドライブが書き込み禁止ディスクであったり、フォルダ内のファイルを開いていると削除できません。なお、この場合はエラーメッセージが異なります。